# App on Google Play Store and other store?

Tags: android, google-play

Currently my app is listed in Google Play Store. I would like to list the same app on other Android app store. Is it possible to list an app in Google Play Store and other Android app stores too? Is it against Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms and conditions of Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing your Android apps through Google Play is **non-exclusive**; you may choose to distribute your applications through other channels as well. Keep in mind the version published in the store must comply with all Google Play policies.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/142471